# Converting an SQL date to store in a PHP variable

Tags: php, sql, date, row

OK so I have researched this question on various other questions that people have asked and I non of them have worked for my problem.  I am grabbing data from a server and getting the time difference between start date and finish date.  Where the problem starts is that there are values that do not have a finish date because they are still in progress so the value is null.  What I am trying to do is take the values that have null in them and replace it with a current `timestamp` so that I can get the time difference so far in time. I have tried many different solutions that I have read on this site such as converting the date() to a string etc.  Here is my code snippet:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
    if(is_null($row['TimeDiffinMin'])){
        $time = $row['StartDate'];
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $time)));
        $TempTime = $date - date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $FebTotal += $TempTime;
        }
    else{ 
        $FebTotal += $row['TimeDiffinMin'];
        }
    $QueryLength ++;    
}
if($QueryLength < 1 || $FebTotal < 1){
    $FebAvg = '0.00';
    }
enter code hereElse{
$FebAvg = $FebTotal/60/$QueryLength;
}
```

And here is the error, it is producing:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be 
converted to string in... on line 94
```

Comment: Which line is line 94?

Comment: Did you look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: the 4th line of code is 94.  I will check that article out

Comment: can you print var_dump/var_export of `$row`?

Comment: For gods sake - use DateTime...